# Avoid sending response in java (tomcat)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Is there a way to prevent the response to be sent at all?
Lets say "I don't like you. And I don't even want to bother to tell you that".

Particulary. I don't like those robots that use IE useragents. And since they follow some patterns they are not dificult to detect (They request fast, Same Ip, Same UA, and a missing cookie in the second request). Or "I don't like your 100 request you made from that same ip address during the last 20 seconds".

Intuition would say that if you decide in a filter not to call "chain.dofilter(...)" could prevent the response being sent.
Am I right.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Just make sure you close the connection/response object output stream.  A filter should work just fine.

Comment: If you want to be mean, close it on garbage collection (tricky). So the caller waits for the timeout O:-)